# Problems in automatically set reference color

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, deconvolution

I was trying to segment blue cells from the image, [image]

I found that using color distance method is highly effective, however, I can only manually set the reference color in RGB. Since I want to do batch processing, I need to automatically select reference color, is there any good solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to present two very basic image processing approaches for this problem. Maybe one of them is useful for you.

Load input image:

```
cells = imread('cells.png');
```

**Approach #1**

Select the blue channel of the input image:

```
cellsBlue = cells(:, :, 3);
imshow(cellsBlue)
```

[image: Blue channel of input image]

Do some thresholding. A very simple version could be:

```
cellsSegm = cellsBlue < 100;
imshow(cellsSegm)
```

[image: Thresholding in blue channel]

Afterwards you will need to apply some morphological filters to improve the masks.

**Approach #2**

Convert input image to [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color space:

```
cellsHSV = rgb2hsv(cells);
imshow(cellsHSV)
```

[image: HSV color space]

Select the "saturation" channel of the HSV image:

```
cellsSat = cellsHSV(:, :, 2);
imshow(cellsSat)
```

[image: Saturation channel of HSV image]

Do some thresholding. A very simple version could be (attention, HSV values are double values between 0 and 1):

```
cellsSegm = cellsSat > 0.5;
imshow(cellsSegm)
```

[image: Thresholding in saturation channel]

Afterwards you will need to apply some morphological filters to improve the masks.